# Прошу объяснить наследование в питоне(Python)

Tags: python, ооп, классы, множественное-наследование

У меня стоит задача создать класс *Фигура* и унаследовать от него класс *Куб*, который в свою очередь должен уметь считать свою площадь или периметр(неважно) по СПИСКУ ПОВЕРХНОСТЕЙ т.е. примерно так [Square, Square, Square, Square, Square, Square]

Код ниже, я не могу понять как мне объединить и вывести например значение из класса Square и вообще заставить ее работать. 
Не могу сообразить какая магия должна произойти чтоб  посчитать сумму  этих поверхностей,
например так

```
summa = sum([Square, Square, Square, Square, Square, Square])
```

---

```
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod

class Figure(ABC):
    def __init__(self, length: int) -> None:
        self.length = length

    @abstractmethod
    def square(self):
        pass

class Cube(Figure):
    def __init__(self, length, height):
        super().__init__(length)
        self.square_cub = 0

    def square(self):
        self.square_cub = [Square, Square, Square, Square, Square, Square]
        return sum(self.square_cub)

class Square(Figure):

    @classmethod
    def square(cls):
        sq_obj = cls.length ** 2
        return cls.sq_obj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спустя фикс кучи логических неурядиц получился вот такой пример рабочего кода.

```
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod

class Figure(ABC):
    def __init__(self, length: int) -> None:
        self.length = length

    @abstractmethod
    def square(self):
        pass

class Square(Figure):

    def square(self):
        sq_obj = self.length ** 2
        return sq_obj
        
class Cube(Figure):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super().__init__(length)
        self.square_cub = 0
        self.square_cub = [Square(length) for i in range(6)]

    def square(self):
        s = 0
        for i in self.square_cub:
            s += i.square()
        return s
        
cube = Cube(2)
print(cube.square())
```

#### Что здесь происходит?

Сначала мы объявляем абстрактный класс `Figure`. Он абстрактный потому что логика одного его поля не определена, значит он может использоваться только для наследования. Наследуем от класса фигуры класс квадрата, в котором доопределяем абстрактный метод. Такой класс можно использовать.

> @classmethod используется для получения первым аргументом ссылки не на объект, а на класс. Но логика у вас была написана очевидна относящаяся к объекту.

Потом мы определяем класс куба и тоже наследуем его от фигуры. И тоже переопределяем метод получения площади.

> У вас был список заполненный 6 **классами** квадратов, а не объектами квадратов.

Из геометрических соображений - куб определяется одной величиной - размером грани. Делаем соответсвующие вычисления. Советую почитать больше об ООП в python на https://younglinux.info/oopython/course

Comment: Благодарю, это просто часть большей задачки, поэтому убрал излишки из кода (где увидел, height- неувидел, но он нужен). Самое ценное в def square(self): я пробовал сумму посчитать от объекта :))

Answer (score 2):

Для получения суммы используйте магический метод [**radd**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__):

```py
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod

class Figure(ABC):
    def __init__(self, length: int) -> None:
        self.length = length

    @abstractmethod
    def square(self) -> int:
        pass

    def __radd__(self, s: int) -> int:
        return self.square() + s

class Square(Figure):
    def square(self) -> int:
        return self.length ** 2

class Cube(Figure):
    def square(self) -> int:
        return Square(self.length).square() * 6

summa = sum([Square(4), Square(3)])
print(summa) # 25
summa = sum([Cube(2), Cube(1), Square(5)])
print(summa) # 55
```

Comment: Спасибо за интересное решение, буду посмотреть!,